# Pulling from a Mercurial repository using Git

Tags: git, mercurial

There is a Mercurial repository I need to pull from, no other operation is required. I already have Git and would rather not install and configure Mercurial just for this operation.

Searching through the web and SO brings up many interoperability plugins for Mercurial; there is also [git-remote-hg](https://github.com/fingolfin/git-remote-hg) but all of these require Mercurial which I would rather avoid installing.

Is there an option to replace the command

```
hg+ssh://hg@bitbucket.org/<name-of-repository>
```

with some Git <sup>(clone?)</sup> command? Installing a small plugin for Git *is* an option.

Comment: You have not another way, except Git-remote-hg for *this* directions: Git-Jungs sollten leiden

Answer (score 0):

1. Git-remote-hg does NOT require (and not required) Mercurial at all
2. Git-remote-hg is part of Git since at least 1.8
3. Fingolfin's git-remote-hg is needed only if remote Mercurial is 3.2 or newer, otherwise you still can use felipec's (core) version

Comment: Hmm, the documentation for git-remote-hg clearly states `To use this tool under Unix-based operating systems [...], first make sure that you have [...] and Mercurial installed.`

Comment: Furthermore, I have git 2.8.1 and it says, `fatal: Unable to find remote helper for 'hg'`.

Comment: @interDist - https://github.com/felipec/git-remote-hg/blob/master/README.asciidoc

Comment: Well, the README is wrong. If you look into the code, you will see right at the top, `from mercurial import ...`. I just tried, though, as you say and Python complains `ImportError: No module named mercurial`. So your #1 is clearly incorrect.